# When Measuring Altitude for a High Altitude Balloon does Temperature Matter?

Tags: pressure, temperature, atmospheric-science, home-experiment, space

When I look at the High Altitude Ballon results from people online that have launched DIY balloons (that have posted their data) I can see that their claimed top altitude (based on the pressure they measured) matches closely with the NASA published Properties of Atmosphere for that same pressure.  Link for NASA Properties of Atmosphere 1976: (https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19770009539.pdf)

The inconsistency always seems to be with regard to temperature. It seems as though the measured temperature can vary significantly from the NASA published tables.

My question is do I need to perform a correction for measured altitude if temperature doesn't match the published data? Some examples I've seen:

Claim 1: 
Altitude = 24,800m
Measured Pressure = 26.075 mb
Measured Temperature = -19.16deg C

Claim 2:
Altitude = 31,000m
Measured Pressure = 10.34mb
Measured Temperature = -22.39deg C

In both claims, the measured pressure matches closely with the listed table altitude from NASA (see Pgs 76 & 77) but the temperatures miss by 20 - 30 degrees. Are the claims correct or did they miss a step in figuring out how high they truly went?